# pandas resample with absolute max

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame (with datetime index) e.g.

```
2017-01-01 00:00:00    -8.64
2017-01-01 01:00:00     1.02
2017-01-01 02:00:00     1.03
2017-01-01 03:00:00     0.00
2017-01-01 04:00:00    -1.01
2017-01-01 05:00:00    -3.57
2017-01-01 06:00:00    -4.18
2017-01-01 07:00:00    7.73
```

I'd like to resample this to 4Hours with the absolute maximum value, i.e the result should be

```
2017-01-01 00:00:00    -8.64
2017-01-01 04:00:00    7.73
```

But I cant find any way to to do this. I tried df.resample('4H').max(key=abs)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can pass to `apply`

```
df.resample('4h').apply(lambda x : max(x, key = abs))
Out[234]: 
2017-01-01 00:00:00   -8.64
2017-01-01 04:00:00    7.73
Freq: 4H, Name: caonima, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Careful, temporal voids (i.e. your data has a gap of >4h in this case) will throw an `max() arg is an empty sequence` ValueError.

Comment: @Adrian you can handle the error in this case in python 3.4+ by providing the ```default``` argument to the ```max()``` function  e.g ```max(x, key = abs, default = np.NaN)```